# Two block-level elements; why do I need float on both to position them side by side?

Tags: html, css

This is a very basic question about floats but I couldn't find an answer with search engines.

When I have two block-level elements (divs for example) and I need them next to each other, why is it not enough to give the first one of them the float:left -property? Why do I need to float both of the divs to put the second next to the first instead of below it?

Here is a code example:

### HTML

```
<div id="box_wrap">
    <div id="box1">
        <h2>Box1 text</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <h2>Box2 text</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
#box1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Copypasted your code (excluding css for #box2) and they are next to each other http://jsfiddle.net/7tmmk/

Comment: You don't. Defining one element that is floated left is sufficient...

Comment: @xec: Yeah well if you copy and paste the second rule and exclude *just* the `float` declaration you'll see something entirely different.

Comment: @BoltClock well spotted. having a closer look

Comment: You don't have to specify `foat:left` for every `div`. Using the Cascade (Cascading Style Sheets) you're able to write: #box_wrap > div {float:left;}

Comment: @gearsdigital: That's still specifying it for every element. Nothing to do with the cascade at all.

Comment: @gearsdigital That's not what cascading means.

Comment: Uhum...yes, sorry i meant inheritance.

Comment: @gearsdigital: Not inheritance either...

Comment: @gearsdigital this isn't inheritance either. you're specifically selecting all children divs of the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats are removed from normal document flow, and is floated left of the contents of `#box2`, but not the div itself. In essence there isn't enough room. You can see this if you give `#box2` a 60% width.

You can change this behavior by giving the second box its own block formatting context. One property that does this is setting `overflow: hidden`

```
#box2 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/7tmmk/2/

For other ways of giving an element its own block formatting context see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Block_formatting_context

For more information on this and other things `overflow: hidden` does, check out http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats

Comment: +1. And a really good way to demonstrate this fact is to take the OPs code (here: http://jsfiddle.net/a6B29/) and vary box2's width between 30%, 40%, and 50%, and/or put a thick outline around box2. Funny-odd behavior, but makes sense with this answer.

Comment: Note that floats create block formatting contexts too, so floating `#box1` also gives it its own.