# What happens to the Content that follows the element with float property

Tags: html, css, css-float

Just saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999103/two-block-level-elements-why-do-i-need-float-on-both-to-position-them-side-by-s#) on stackoverflow.

consider below **markup**:

```
<div id="box_wrap">
    <div id="box1">
        <h2>Box1 text</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <h2>Box2 text</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div
```

with **CSS**:

```
#box1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 30%;
}
```

divs appear one over another i.e. ([corresponding fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbDqT/))

[image]

but when I give `#box2` , a width higher than that of `#box1` i.e. `width:34%`, then this happens: ([corresponding fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbDqT/1/))

[image]

and for even higher width of `#box2` (comparatively to that of `#box1`) i.e. `width:50%`, finally the desired effect appears. ([corresponding fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbDqT/2/))

[image]

Notice blue box i.e. box with `float:left` i.e. `#box1` has `width:30%` and Red box i.e. box with no float property i.e. `#box2` has `width:50%`, still blue got rendered larger than Red.

Also, for no width or `width:auto` for `#box2` it produces the desired effect.

**desired effect**: `#div2` should get aligned to the right of the `#div1`

Can anyone please explain to me, what is happening? what am i missing?

(also didn't know how to raise this question with a suitable title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the elements after the floated elements get their contents wrapped around the floated element. 
In you first case when both div's are of same width, the 2nd div can't wrap around the first div because a thing has to be wider (lager) then the thing it have to wrap itself around.

In your second case, the box2 gets wider than box1 and wraps its contents around box1 as much as possible.

In your third case when the box2 is sufficiently wider than box1, it still is wrapping around box1 but there isn't sufficient content to be displayed below box1. Adding some more content to box2 will make it clear for you http://jsfiddle.net/GbDqT/4/. This jsfiddle contains `width: auto` for box2 and some extra content.

**Update:** the reason why the box2 *appears* less wider than box1 is that (you can imagine) that the box1 is *overlaying* on top of box2. So most part of box2 is hidden under box1, but the content of box2 is pushed toward right because of the floating box1

**source**:[developer.mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float)